# На каком языке программирования лучше писать поискового робота?

Tags: поиск, php, c++

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос: на как каком языке программирования лучше писать поискового
робота? Писал на PHP, но робот получился медленный.

Если писать на c++, то каким способом лучше общаться с сервером через cURL, LWP, Urdl или winsock?

Comment: На любом языке, программы на котором работают быстрее PHP. Я бы порекомендовал попробовать Java.

Comment: Медленный в чём?

- Сетевые соединения?
- Медленная работа с базой данных?
- Медленная обработка результатов? 
- Присутствуют сложные математические вычисления?

В таких сложных вопросах, необходимо находить узкие места в архитектуре программного комплекса. 

Я бы конечно дал абстрактный ответ:
Язык C++. Низкоуровневая работа через winsock.
При правильной разработке повышение производительности может составить от 30% до 5000%. Но если не понимать принципы работы на C++, то вместо роста будет падение производительности 30% - 1000%.

Comment: @manking, если не понимать принципы работы С++, то через некоторое время может наступить падение системы. Если, например, не освобождать память.

Comment: @mikillskegg
в таких случаях много чего может приключиться, что сведет успешность задачи на нет.

Но и выхода другого нет. Просто переписать программу, на другой язык в надежде что он "быстрее" и всё будет 'круто' путь в никуда.

Если требуется высокая производительность, придётся понимать как, что где и почему работает так то, а не так то. 

Есть такое понятие как оптимизация. Простая расстановка флагов по коду, и выяснение времени работы каждого может дать чёткие ответы в каком направлении двигаться. 

Вот если бы автор указал где у него узкие места, тогда бы что нибудь можно было говорить.

Comment: Откуда такие глупые вопросы? На машинном коде естественно

Comment: На всякий случай - если реализация на машинных кодах будет подтормаживать, то стоит глянуть в сторону программирования на [Машине Тьюринга](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0) или [РАМ-Машине](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%9C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0). На первой проще программировать, зато вторая практичнее в случае сложных арифметических операций.

Comment: assambler)

Comment: @Котик, а разве машина Тьюринга не есть CPU?

Comment: @SoloMio, а Вы на ссылочки в комментарии @Котика покликайте - и сразу все станет ясно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python. Вот [курс о создании поисковой системы с примерами на питоне](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs101/CourseRev/apr2012) на Udacity

Comment: спасибо огромное за помощь

Comment: Почему такой однозначный ответ? Почему не подходят Java, Perl, Go, Lisp или тот же С++? Обоснуйте, пожалуйста. Кроме того, как ни крути, а Python (при всей моей любви к нему) - довольно медленный язык, а у человека проблемы именно со скоростью.

Comment: В каком месте у Вас медленно?

Comment: да уж - питон тормозила, по сравнению с тем же с++

Comment: Мне кажется, или типичный поисковый робот будет упираться в сеть, а не в разбор/индексацию?

Answer (score 0):

- Я бы посоветовал перед тем как переписывать уже готовый продукт на языке `X,` как минимум провести профайлинг и убедиться в том, что тормоза возникают из-за каких-то особенностей языка.
- Если это действительно так ("вот блин, как же так, `substr` в моем любимом языке `X` работает 3 секунды, да, надо переписать на `Y`"), в чем лично я сомневаюсь, то тогда уже можно думать о переписывании.
- Если нет, то соптимизируйте хотспоты и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Programming Recipes for C# Bots](http://www.amazon.com/HTTP-Programming-Recipes-C-Bots/dp/0977320677)

Answer (score -1):

Голосую за С++ , по скорости можно выиграть довольно много

Answer (score -2):

Если выбирать между С++ и PHP, то конечно же си -шка. Он просто быстрее пхпихи. Хотя, если вы мастер пхп, но плохо знаете с++, то лучше пхп. А если они у вас примерно на одинаковом уровне - то конечно с++